# TDengine supported timezone format

Tags: timestamp, timezone, tdengine

To insert a timestamp into TDengine I tried the following formats which are legitimately defined in RFC3339 and ISO8601 standard:

```
"2018-1-8 9:1:1.952";
"2018-1-8T1:1:1.952-08:00";
"2018-1-8 1:1:1.952-08:00";
"2018-1-81:1:1.952-08:00";
```

I was expecting insertion of the above timezone formats would have the same result but for some of them the timezone shifting looks incorrect. Anyone know what timezone formats does TDengine support?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine currently support:

1. RFC 3339 standard expression
2. Using 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' format when using taoSQL to insert